# How to share action bar and items on it between activities

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This is probably extremely simple, but I have two activities that both need the same items in the action bar, but when I start the second activity (the first is main) the action overflow menu disappears. I understand that the action bar is unique to the activity its created in, but I want to know how to use the same action bar in various activities. Thanks

Edit: here is some code that might help with my second issue of action bar items not working out of the first activity:
    package com.example.wfhsregistry;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


}
     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.menuSettings) {
             return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }  
}
```

And here is my first class that starts my first activity:

```
package com.example.wfhsregistry;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;

public class Main extends MenuActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread logotimer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent(
                            "com.example.wfhsregistry.MENU");
                    startActivity(menuIntent);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        logotimer.start();

    }

    public void getOverflowMenu() {

        try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
                    .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if (menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Inflate same options menu.

Comment: Use the same menu you're inflating in the first Activity in your second activity. Just inflate the same menu within the 2 different Activities

Comment: @Jack That is duplicated code; however, you could extend a class that has that menu inflated and reuse the code. See mlaHackingIsMagic answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use inheritance.

Create a new Activity lets call it MenuActivity and place all the options logic in.

```
MenuActivity extends Activity
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
...
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
...
}
```

And now your 2 activities just need to extend it (so they will inherit MenuActivity's logic unless you override its method without calling super)

```
MainActivity extends MenuActivity
```

And

```
Activity2 extends MenuActivity
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! I put my onOptionsItemSelected() method in MenuActivity but when I want to hit the settings button (which is in the overflow menu) it only works in the first activity that opens in the app. Do you have any idea why this is? Thanks for your help!

Comment: So the button is there in both but only works in one?
What is the logic that you are trying to execute?

Comment: The only item in the toolbar that I currently have is a settings tab that simply opens the activity. The start activity() for it is in MenuActivity in the onOptionsItemSelected, so I don't know why it wouldn't work in any activity because they all extend MenuActivity. I can post the code shortly if it helps.

Comment: So in your menuActivity it doesn't look like you execute any logic if a button is selected.
if (id == R.id.menuSettings) {return true;}
So you return true but never execute any logic. I imagine you want to do something like
Intent menuIntent = new Intent(               "com.example.wfhsregistry.MENU");
startActivity(menuIntent);

Comment: Yes, that's it! I had forgot to put the settings Intent into MenuActivity and had left it only in the first class. Everything works, thanks!